# How to run Eventmachine server in a sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventmachine

I have Rails 4.1.5 app deployed on a server having IP let's say 1.2.3.4. A third-party client app is continuously sending xml by connecting to my server via telnet throughout the day.

I've used [Eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) to start server on port 2000. It works fine. The problem is I'm executing this code on terminal. I want this to be in a place that runs automatically and continuously listens to the traffic coming from third-party client.

```
module NeoConnex
  class XmlParser < EM::Connection

    def post_init
      puts "Initial Server Message"
    end

    def receive_data(data)
      puts "Raw Data: #{data}"
    end

  end
end

EM.run do
  EM.start_server("a.b.c.d", 2000, NeoConnex::XmlParser)
  puts "Listening on port 2000"
end
```

I tried to use a Sidekiq worker:

```
class StartServerWorker
include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perfom

  end
end
```

Now Should I place all the code in the sidekiq perform method? and how to set recurrence of this sidekiq worker so that it can listen continuously on port 2000.